# How to add object of type dictionary as BsonElement in BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, dictionary, mongodb-.net-driver

Well I am trying to perform insert batch operation. For that I am creating an array of BsonDocuemt. To each BsonDocument In array, I am adding BsonElements.

Question Class (Model):

```
public class Question
{
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string QuestionName { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string, VariableDetails> Rules { get; set; }

        public List<Question> QuestionsList { get; set; }
}

public class VariableDetails
{
        public string variableType { get; set; }
        public string min { get; set; }
        public string max { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am trying to form array of BsonDocuemts as follows:

```
public void batchInsert(Question Model)
{
     _collection = _db.GetCollection<Question>("Question");
     BsonDocument[] batch = new BsonDocument[Model.QuestionsList.Count];
     int count = 0;

     foreach (Question question in Model.QuestionsList )
     {
            BsonDocument bsonDoc = new BsonDocument();
            bsonDoc.Add(new BsonElement("QuestionName", question.QuestionName ));

            //Following line is in error
            bsonDoc.Add(new BsonElement("Rules", question.Rules));
            //Argument type 'Systems.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, VariableDetails>' is not assignable to parameter type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'.

            batch[count] = bsonDoc;
            count++;
     }
     _collection.InsertBatch(batch);
}
```

I am able to add property of type string as BsonElement in BsonDocument, Not able to do so with property of type Dictionary.

I want the final insert in db should be like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54757796bb63bc08b481ad86"),
    "Name" : "Question1",
    "Rules" : {
        "a1" : {
            "variableType" : "1dPI",
            "min" : "1",
            "max" : "9"
        },
        "a2" : {
            "variableType" : "1dPI",
            "min" : "1",
            "max" : "9"
        }
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54757796bb63bc08b481ad86"),
    "Name" : "Question2",
    "Rules" : {
        "d1" : {
            "variableType" : "1dPI",
            "min" : "1",
            "max" : "9"
        },
        "f3" : {
            "variableType" : "1dPI",
            "min" : "1",
            "max" : "9"
        }
    }
}
```

**My question is how can I add property of type Dictionary as BsonElement in BsonDocuemt?**

Comment: try BsonArray instead of array of BsonDocument

Comment: @Disposer - I am not able to find, how to use BsonArray in my scenario. Can you show me how should I use it in my case?

Comment: @Disposer - Anyways I got the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just needed to add nested BsonDocument as an element to parent BsonDocument. That's it!

```
public void batchInsert(Question Model)
{
 _collection = _db.GetCollection<Question>("Question");
 BsonDocument[] batch = new BsonDocument[Model.QuestionList.Count];

 int count = 0;

 foreach (Question question in Model.QuestionList)
 {
     BsonDocument rulesBsonDoc = new BsonDocument();

     foreach (KeyValuePair<string, VariableDetails> qTemp in question.Rules)
     {
         string variableName = qTemp.Key;
         VariableDetails variableDetails = qTemp.Value;
         string variableType = variableDetails.variableType;
         string min = variableDetails.min;
         string max = variableDetails.max;

         BsonDocument childBsonDoc = new BsonDocument();
         childBsonDoc.Add(new BsonElement("variableType", variableType));
         childBsonDoc.Add(new BsonElement("min", min));
         childBsonDoc.Add(new BsonElement("max", max));    

         rulesBsonDoc.Add(new BsonElement(variableName, childBsonDoc));
      }

      BsonDocument bsonDoc = new BsonDocument();
      bsonDoc.Add(new BsonElement("Name", question.Name));
      bsonDoc.Add(new BsonElement("Rules", rulesBsonDoc));
      batch[count] = bsonDoc;
      count++;
  }
  _collection.InsertBatch(batch);
}
```